Считывание информации из com-порта на языке python
Я использую язык python и библиотеку serial, и я считываю информацию с com порта таким образом:
self.connect=serial.Serial(self.combox_port.get(), baudrate=int(self.baudrate), bytesize=int(self.bytesize), stopbits=int(self.stopbits))
print("Подключение установлено")
while self.main_flag:
     self.line=self.connect.readline().decode().strip()
     if self.line:
         print(self.line)

но у меня абсолютно ничего не выводиться, в чем проблема?
P.S. Информацию отправляет контроллер, в виде ASCII символов

Лютый поллинг не даёт продыху системе. В вашем другом вопросе же ссылку указали на объяснение

это мой первый вопрос на эту тему

Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример. Какие данные шлёт контроллер? Что за контроллер? Как настроен? Откуда увереность что контроллер вообще что то шлёт?

контроллер данные точно отправляет, уверен потому что проверял через утилиту другую. все принимается, но почему то именно через мое не работает

данные в моем случае просто отчет о проведенных тестах

это мой первый вопрос на эту тему - Ну нам-то не гони ©Жмурки

вместо непонятных обвинений, могли бы помочь

self.line=self.connect.readline().decode('utf-8')

Проблему решило указание декодирования.
